# Need to store JavaScript variables for use on other pages?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, save

Here's an outline of what I want to do.

I want to store the value of a JavaScript variable in some way and then, on another HTML page, retrieve that value and assign to another different JavaScript variable. Is there a way to do this? Also, I'm a bit of a newbie so I need a tutorial not just a method. Please help

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use XML? When using JavaScript, JSON is much better format for storing & retrieving data.

Comment: I'm new to this XML was just an idea in not sure what the best way is. I'll look up JSON

Comment: Would cookies do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use XMLHttpRequest to read XML, however, I am not sure if you can write.
Try this link and see if it is what you are looking for:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to invent your own data storage method. Have a look at [sessionStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).